# Regular Expression for field must contain at least 2 non-space alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, validation

Rule: field must contain at least 2 non-space alphanumeric characters.

please any one can guide us how to write the regular expression

thanks in advance....

Comment: since when space is an alphanumeric character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match one alphanumeric character followed by zero or more characters followed by another alphanumeric character:

```
\w.*\w
```

If the validation automatically adds ^ and $, you have to match the characters before and after also:

```
.*\w.*\w.*
```

The `\w` code matches A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _. If you have a different definition for aplhanumeric characters, you can use a set of characters instead, for example:

```
[A-Za-z0-9].*[A-Za-z0-9]
```

Comment: i am going to write regular expression in SQL server 2008...
we developed the REGEX function in VS2008 and we deployed that in SQL..    so by passing Regular expression it will validate the input data....

Comment: oO We have almost identical answers) So I'd better delete mine.

Comment: I can't say that I've ever heard of an underscore being regarded as an alphanumeric character. If you have, please provide a source. See, for example, [this](https://oeis.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_alphanumeric_characters). I suggest you reference your second regex only.